# how to deal with how to make the completion queue not pay attention to a certain stream when this flow is not open

Tags: grpc

I would like to ask Grpc to create an RPC service for server-side streams, and this service uses asynchronous processing, how to deal with how to make the completion queue not pay attention to a certain stream when this flow is not open. Attached is my conjecture:

void StopMonitoringStream(grpc::ServerContext* context) {
bool monitor_completion_queue = false;
context->AddTrailingMetadata("monitor_completion_queue", std::to_string(monitor_completion_queue));
}

where monitor_completion_queue is the completion queue that I defined. Is it reasonable, please

When I use Grpc as the event processing center for publishing and subscribing, I need a thread to use the completion queue to collect all subscribers (the subscription service RPC uses the server-side stream) and then distribute the server-side stream to each thread, and when publish is released, the corresponding stream is published, and after being assigned to each thread, the completion queue of this thread will no longer pay attention to the action of the stream so as not to affect the arrival time of other subscribers

Comment: CompletionQueue is not a bool, but an class from grpc, check the examples: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.57.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc